# How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly bracket in TeXmacs

Tags: texmacs

Here is the photo. How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly bracket in TeXmacs?

[image]

I tried inserting Equation and Equations.   I didn't manage to insert the curly bracket.
In LaTeX, it's like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
    f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    \frac{x^2-x}{x},& \text{if } x\geq 1\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems better suited to http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please consider supporting the proposed creation of a TeXmacs SE site here: https://area51.stackexchange.com where such kind of questions can be discussed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it by myself.

In equation mode you can click on `Insert a table` in the tool bar, then choose `Choice`, grid with with one-sided curly bracket will be automatically generated.

Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE1B8.png